# Mixing motion-layout and Teacup

Tags: autolayout, rubymotion

I'm trying to mix motion-layout and Teacup in a RubyMotion project. I've created an example view helper to illustrate my problem:

```
module Teacup::Layout

  def example(name, options = {})

    subview UIView, name do
      subview UILabel, "#{name}_label".to_sym, text: options[:label]

      auto do
        horizontal "|-[#{name}_label]-|"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I call `example(:example), text: "Test"` inside a `layout` block, my code throws the following exception:

```
(main)> 2013-10-25 13:40:45.989 rui[55552:80b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format:
example_label is not a key in the views dictionary.
H:|-[example_label]-|
```

If I omit the motion-layout code and inspect the views, the `example_label` view is a child of the `example` view. What's going on here?

Comment: Maybe try using a string instead of a symbol? I'm not an auto-layout expert.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't do the trick.

Comment: I think this code should work, I'll play with it tomorrow! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation for Teacup, it says:

```
# if you need to apply these to a different view, or if you want to assign
# different names to use in the ASCII strings
# auto(layout_view=self.view, layout_subviews={}, &layout_block)
```

Due to the 'dynamic' nature of the creation of all these views, and the layout (motion-layout) being in a subview instead of a layout (teacup), it just might be getting confused, though subview and layout are similar.

Anyway, try being very specific about which views are going into the `auto` block using the suggestion from the documentation, then there can be no ambiguity about what should be in the layout.